# Symfony generate CSV character encoding

Tags: php, symfony, csv, character-encoding

I am using the following code to generate CSV files in Symfony 2.0.

```
    $filename = "file.csv";
    $response = $this->render('propesqBundle:Relatorio:' . $session->get('idRelatorio' . $key) . '.csv.html.twig', array('rows' => $session->get('resultado' . $key)));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'Content-type: application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $filename);
    return $response;
```

But when I open the file, the words should have the characters `&` replaced with `&amp;` and the single quote `'` with `&#039;`.

Comment: I'm guessing your twig templates are escaping the output.  You need to filter everything though | raw.  Personally I find it easier to just use fputcsv and print to a buffer.

Comment: Thank you I will try to use fputcsv.